# How to change/add CSS inside of iframe by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to add css properties in a iframe div by using jQuery but it's not working.

**Html Code:-**

```
<html>
    <body>
      <iframe id='iframeId' src='api.php?abc=xyz..'>
        <html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <div class='change-class'> //require <div class='change-class' style='background-color:black'>
              .......

            </div>

          </body>
        </html>
      </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS Code:-**

I try below code but doesn't get any result.

```
$('.change-class').css('background-color','black');
$("#iframeId").contents().find(".change-class").attr('style','background-color=black');
```

Comment: Is it similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: Are you getting "different origin error" while getting `$("#iframeId").contents().find(".change-class")`

Comment: i think you shuld forgot about this. because it's not possible untill your css is not in that iframe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this the iframe src document should also have to be on same domain to access iframe's dom nodes, if you have both pages on same domain then you can do this:

```
$("#iframeId").contents().find(".change-class").css('background-color', 'black');
```

Comment: Question... shouldnt it be `.css()` rather than `.attr()`...?

Comment: if both file are on same domain then why he want to add css via javascript. he should add css directly to inside iframe.

Comment: @jigneshkheni sometimes when you don't have ajax implemented but you want to change the view that is where iframe mostly used.

Comment: still not working..actually this is a cross domain for iframe.

Comment: @chotesah then it is not possible due to security reasons. only the pages at same domains can be accessible.

Comment: Very good, i was really searching for this solution. great work @Jai

Answer (score 0):

You can find use like this way:

```
var iframe = $('iframe'); 
$(".change-class", iframe.contents()).addClass('border');
```